# why there is different output in for-loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, double-quotes, ifs

**Linux bash**: why the two shell script as follow had different result?

```
[root@yumserver ~]# data="a,b,c";IFS=",";for i in $data;do echo $i;done
a
b
c
[root@yumserver ~]# IFS=",";for i in a,b,c;do echo $i;done                     
a b c
```

expect output: the second script also output:

```
a
b
c
```

I should understood what @M.NejatAydin means。Thanks also @EdMorton,@HaimCohen!

```
[root@k8smaster01 ~]# set -x;data="a,b,c";IFS=",";echo $data;echo "$data";for i in $data;do echo $i;done
+ data=a,b,c
+ IFS=,
+ echo a b c
a b c
+ echo a,b,c
a,b,c
+ for i in '$data'
+ echo a
a
+ for i in '$data'
+ echo b
b
+ for i in '$data'
+ echo c
c
[root@k8smaster01 ~]# IFS=",";for i in a,b,c;do echo $i;done                    
+ IFS=,
+ for i in a,b,c
+ echo a b c
a b c
```

Comment: And I still confused that why $data (quoted and unquoted) has different result in first script.

Comment: There is no `$data` in the second script.

Comment: [@M.NejatAydin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74674566/1745001) tells you exactly why. If it's not clear you should ask them to clarify whatever point is unclear. Also, do `set -x` before running both command lines to see what they actually do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word splitting is performed on the results of unquoted *expansions* (specifically, parameter expansions, command substitutions, and arithmetic expansions, with a few exceptions which are not relevant here). The literal string `a,b,c` in the
second `for` loop is not an *expansion* at all. Thus, word splitting is not performed on that literal string. But note that, in the second example, word splitting is still performed on `$i` (an unquoted *expansion*) in the command `echo $i`.

It seems the point of confusion is where and when the `IFS` is used. It is used in the word splitting phase following an (unquoted) expansion. It is **not** used when the shell reads its input and breaks the input into words, which is an earlier phase.

Note: `IFS` is also used in other contexts (eg, by the `read` builtin command) which are not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 2):

@HaimCohen explained in detail *why* you get a different result with those two approaches. Which is what you asked. His answer is correct, it should get upvoted and accepted.

Just a trivial addition from my side: you can easily modify the second of your approaches however if you define the variable on the fly:

```
IFS=",";for i in ${var="a,b,c"};do echo $i;done
```

Comment: [HaimCohen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74674364/1745001) states WHAT happens, t doesn't explain WHY it happens. [M. Nejat Aydin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74674566/1745001) explains WHY ("Word splitting is performed on the results of unquoted expansions").